# PNaCl: Handle another message while already in 'HandleMessage' function?

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm using PNaCl and I'm in a situation where first I receive a message that is handled in the 'HandleMessage' function as the normal way, but then in the current HandleMessage execution, I need to wait for a user input that would come from an other message in order to complete the execution.

I'm wondering if this is possible to do that (handling a message while already waiting in the 'HandleMessage' function) ? And if so, can someone give me a trick ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HandleMessage` is currently called on one thread, the main thread. So you cannot receive a message while you are handling another message.

We typically suggest you spawn a new thread to do your work, and leave the main thread to handle messages, and queue them for the new thread to handle. Take a look at the `nacl_io_demo` example in the SDK for an example of this technique (found in `examples/demo/nacl_io`).

Another solution is to use a state machine; i.e. keep track of your current state in a variable instead of on the stack.

For example:

```
enum State {
  STATE_INIT,
  STATE_WAITING_FOR_INPUT,
  STATE_DO_OTHER_STUFF,
};

State state_;

virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
  switch (state_) {
    case STATE_INIT:
      if (var_message.AsString() == "first_message") {
        state_ = STATE_WAITING_FOR_INPUT;
        // Do some work before you need the user input ...
      }
      break;

    case STATE_WAITING_FOR_INPUT:
      if (var_message.AsString() == "user_input") {
        // Do more work, now that we've received input from the user...
        state_ = STATE_DO_OTHER_STUFF;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```